# javascript variable and value concatenation

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I have a list of variables:

```
subcatlist1 = 'aa';
subcatlist2 = 'bb';
subcatlist3 = 'cc';
```

What i would like to do, is insert the value of a given variable from the option options, into an element, but the 'number' of the variable (ie, 1, 2 or 3)  is itself coming in as a variable, say `itemNumber`.

What I would like to do is:
$(element).html(subcatlist+ itemNumber);

... Which would give the value of `aa` for `itemNumber` = 1

The error that I am getting is: 
`ReferenceError: subcatlist is not defined` - which make sense, because the variable `subcatlist` doesn't exist - only `subcatlist1`, `subcatlist2`, `subcatlist3` exist.

Do how can i concatenate the `subcatlist`+ `itemNumber`  to get a variable that i can use, as `subcatlist1` etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `object` instead of `variable` is better approach in your context,Because you concadenate with variable is wrong.

```
var subcatlist = {1:"aa",2:"bb",3:"cc"}

$(element).html(subcatlist[itemNumber]);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

The solution is to access the needed variable as a property of the containing object.

If defined in the global scope using `var` , in javascript the value is assigned as a property of the [global object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_object), and it can be accessed using the self explanatory keyword `globalThis`

> In JavaScript, there's always a global object defined. In a web browser, when scripts create global variables defined with the var keyword, they're created as members of the global object. (In Node.js this is not the case.)

```js
var subcatlist1 = 'aa';
var subcatlist2 = 'bb';
var subcatlist3 = 'cc';

var itemNumber = parseInt(Math.random() * 3) + 1

$('#test').html(globalThis['subcatlist' + itemNumber])
```

```html
<script 
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test">
```

---

See also ["Variable" variables in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187530/variable-variables-in-javascript)

---

**Original answer**

<s>If having a list of variables is mandatory you could use eval() like this:</s>

$(element).html(eval("subcatlist"+ itemNumber));

*****eval can be harmful and should be avoided in most cases*****